# Low faith & struggles

Tags: imaan, depression

Ok so here’s my story: I grew up in a non-practicing muslim household, my parents both believe in Islam but they don’t pray etc. I am a 16 year old girl and I only actually got to know what Islam really is a few months ago. I am currently praying fajr and maghrib as an Imam told me that I should do that in the beginning and he said to take it slow, but I’m really struggling with everything. Just doing that already seems a bit overwhelming to me as I have anxiety, depression, hypothyroidism and I’m recovering from 2 eating disorders so I’m at a horrible place mentally. I am just extremely tired and I could do nothing all day. The purification process is also something I'm struggling with as I already posted another question. I barely have any friends and no hobbies at all because I’m not even sure which hobbies are permissible but I absolutely hate sports. My grades at school are bad and I have no motivation to study. I don’t really know who to go to for advice because I live in a non muslim country and I only met the imam that I talked to once during holidays when I went to my home country.

Edit: I couldnt get an appointment with my doctor early enough but it’s my 2nd day fasting ramadan and I’m in a lot of pain right now, my whole midsection hurts but I don’t know if I am allowed to break the fast. Advice?

Comment: https://youtu.be/tr6fY1MQmyk

Comment: I watched the video but I’m still not sure if I count as one of those people, I’m scared to make a mistake so I’m not sure

Comment: Ok, break the fast if you feel relaxed by breaking the fast and complete it on another days.

Comment: okay, thank you

Comment: Your welcome,my pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pray in salah and seek Allah's help, know the meanings of duas and surahs which are recited in salah. Start  slowly,take your time in offering salah,don't take it hard on yourself,offer one time salah at first day ,and when you feel that you are ready to offer two times salah in a day and you are comfortable in doing so then offer two times salah in a day,and in the same way by taking your time complete your five times salah in a day,don't forget that Allah is with you ,he wants ease for you not difficulty.
Ramazan is coming,fast in this month(ask the doctor if it is safe for you or not) know the rules of fasting because by fasting you can control on your desires.
In free times you should do something interesting,find your interest,you can be interested in cooking or drawing or reading or playing or sewing or anything, and by engaging yourself in these things you can avoid stress,sadness and many things and you can walk in malls and parks and other places too.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I had a very bad day when I wrote the question and I'm gonna try my best to actually focus on positive things now. (Although I'm still anxious because I feel like I keep doing everything wrong)

Comment: Why do you feel that you are doing everything wrong?

Comment: I don’t know maybe its just whispers in my head but I feel like whenever I pray,do ghusl,wudu or whatever I feel like I might be doing something wrong or leaving something out which is why that takes me a long time as well

Comment: Ignore those thoughts that you are doing something wrong,these thoughts are made by shaitan to deceive you,just do whatever you do without thinking anything, Allah is different from human if you are doing your best and in spite of this you make some mistakes Allah will forgive you, don't worry he is the most merciful,most forgiving. Always remember that Allah is with you.

Comment: thanks, I’ll try my best to ignore it

Comment: If this is helpful ,tick the answer.

Comment: I ticked it now

Answer (score 0):

Serve God with joy as good as you can and He will be your support. Joy in doing right is the better way than doing it from fear. He is the Most Merciful.
Look for support in your place.

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna try

Answer (score 0):

Several youtube channels may also help:

- IlovuAllah
- Prophets path
- Mufti Menk
- Merciful Servant
  (I recommend the first and third and search for solutions to your personal problems within these channels.)

Comment: thanks, i'll check out those channels

Answer (score 0):

Allah knows what you are going through and only Allah knows your circumstances. Put faith in Allah and try to remember him as much as you can. At first it might be hard, and you might stop (inshallah not). However, just remember to take it slow and know that Allah loves you a lot to put you on the path of remembering him more. You and I have a similar story and I’m still trying to learn more about Islam everyday. Put your faith in Allah and do as much as you can, Allah knows your intentions.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is hard and I keep struggling but I'm still trying.